# what's the equivalent of jquery's 'trigger' method without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's the equivalent of *jQuery*'s `trigger` method without *jQuery*?

e.g., how do i do something like `$('.blah').trigger('click');` without *jQuery*?

Comment: This may help u :http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=172865

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For some value of "a very shoddy equivalent":

```
var button = document.getElementById("thebutton")
button.click()
```

Not all browsers (e.g. Firefox!) allow simulated events this way! Using `onclick()` only works if the event is in-line, etc.

Please see [the jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js) and search for "trigger:" (first match) to see all the icky stuff done to "make it work" (a good bit of it is just munging around the jQuery internals, other frameworks make have much simpler examples).

Happy coding.

Comment: This isn't the equivalent of jQuery's `.trigger()`. What about other events? e.g. `resize`, `scroll`, `hashchange`. What about custom events? This doesn't even work cross-browser.

Comment: This is supported as of Firefox 5 according to MDN.

Comment: Also it should noted that calling `click()` does not execute registered event listeners.

Answer (score 34):

event.initMouseEvent("click"...

Here is an example:

```
function simulateClick(elId) {
    var evt;
    var el = document.getElementById(elId);
    if (document.createEvent) {
        evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    }
    (evt) ? el.dispatchEvent(evt) : (el.click && el.click());
}

var foo = document.getElementById("hey");

foo.onclick = function () {alert("bar");}

simulateClick("hey");
```

Answer (score 16):

in Javascript

```
var event = document.createEvent("Event");
event.initEvent("click", false, true); 
document.getElementById("blah").dispatchEvent(event);
```

is equivalent for jQuery trigger as below

```
$('#blah').trigger('click');
```

Comment: `Event.initEvent()` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) use instead [`Event()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)

Answer (score 6):

Create an [Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and pass it to [element.dispatchEvent(event)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

```js
  const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });

  element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

### More info

- Creating and triggering events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#triggering_built-in_events
- All Events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#event_listing

Answer (score 3):

Here is my example. Working perfectly in all situations

```
var d=document.createEvent("MouseEvents"),
    c=document.createEvent("MouseEvents"),
    p=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    d.initMouseEvent("mousedown",true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);
    c.initMouseEvent("click"    ,true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);
    p.initMouseEvent("mouseup"  ,true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);

    var element =// some selector;

    element.dispatchEvent(d);
    element.dispatchEvent(c);
    element.dispatchEvent(p);
```

Comment: `initMouseEvent` is now deprecated.