# Greasemonkey/JQuery click returns array in blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, prototype

I have been on this for the past two days and tried different methods of clicking.
I need to wait for the page to load and then simulate a click. I use:

```
 waitForKeyElements (".button.bbutton.unbind_later", clickOnFollowButton);  
function clickOnFollowButton (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

The simulated click returns what I believe is a JSON array displayed in a blank new page. Example:

```
{"t_ref":"KL26208","price":"1.77","display":"<div class=\"confirm_wrapper\">\n    <h4>Tconfirmation</h4>....."}
```

But when I click manually, I stay on the same page. Part of the page displays a confirmation /thank you message (the page is not reloaded and no new (blank) page when I click manually).

Do I have to parse some data to the click event? How can I simulate the manual click?

The event handler

```
// =====chrome inspect elements snippet ======
handler: function (e){return typeof b===i||e&&b.event.triggered===e.type?t:b.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem,arguments)}
arguments: null
caller: null
elem: button.bbutton.unbind_later
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: Object
constructor: function (e){return typeof b===i||e&&b.event.triggered===e.type?t:b.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem,arguments)}
__proto__: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
```

Comment: Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem. Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [initMouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent)?

Comment: I used the initMouseEvent example from the answer in --> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658849/whats-the-equivalent-of-jquerys-trigger-method-without-jquery)
The result is the same. json array returned in a white page after the click event occurs

Comment: Also tried the answer in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript) ... gives same result