# How to use javascript click method with modifiers (ctrl, shift)

Tags: javascript, html

I need to trigger an ajax-ed element by javascript method:

```
<h:panelGrid id="g" columns="1" onmouseover="window.document.getElementById(aa).click()">
```

and it works, except that it doesn't recognize the modifiers.

I looked here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp and modified the *try it yourself* to look like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction(event)" onclick="alert('click event occured '+event.ctrlKey)">
```

but `ctrlKey` always is `false`.

Is there a way to persuade the click-method to use and forward the modifiers?

Edit: to clarify the "moused" object and the object that should send the ajax-request are different!

Comment: @Barmar: thanks, looks nicer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click with the Control key, it sends the `contextmenu` event instead of the `click` event. If you want a general event for all types of mouse clicks, use `mousedown`.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmousedown="alert('click event occurred ' + event.ctrlKey);">
```

See [what's the equivalent of jquery's 'trigger' method without jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658849/whats-the-equivalent-of-jquerys-trigger-method-without-jquery) for a more detailed answer showing how to synthesize mouse click events, including all the different event parameters.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. I see your example is working, but I don't understand. When I modify the example at w3schools, it doesn't work.

Comment: And I don't see how I could forward that event to my getElementById(aa) object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658849/whats-the-equivalent-of-jquerys-trigger-method-without-jquery for how to simulate different types of click events

Comment: I see the link ... so I don't have to be ashamed that I couldn't find a two-liner to do it. Could you  incorporate the link into your question so that I can accept it?