# Manually triggering a function click event object

Tags: javascript

I've got the following code:

```
function myfunc(e){
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

which returns the event of the clicked target. But I want to trigger that same function without clicking on a target.

Is this possible? is it possible to do something like this?

```
myfunc(document.getElementById('btn').target);
```

Comment: check this, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658849/whats-the-equivalent-of-jquerys-trigger-method-without-jquery

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript

Comment: Answer is probably in the duplicate, and you can check `if( typeof(e) !== 'undefined' ) { ... CODE FOR EVENT OBJECT ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggering a `.click()` with javascript **manually** will directly bind the click to that element so in your case an **event will not be passed** by doing this . Also , `target` is a property of the event object so calling it directly on `getElementById` will not work . Logically once you `getElementById` then you already have your target because **id's are unique** .

On the other hand jquery library allows you to trigger clicks and pass custom data like so :

**Example :**

```
$( "button" ).on( "click", {name: "John"}, sayName);

function sayName(event){

    alert(event.data.name )

}
```

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your function like this, to use with and without event trigger (if you only need the element object)

```
function myfunc(e){
    var ele = e ? e.target : document.getElementById('btn');
    console.log(ele);
}
```